# How can I save data of products from the same template after pressing the add-to-cart button many times and display them in the shopping cart file?

Tags: javascript, html, web-applications, e-commerce, shopping-cart

The code consists of 3 separated HTML files:

1. shop.html - An HTML file representing the shop (from where we can select a product)
2. sproduct.html - An HTML file with a varying content representing a template for the single selected product (includes the "add-to-cart" button, to add the selected product to the shopping cart)
3. cart.html - An HTML file representing the shopping cart (In where I would like to have the list of the selected product from the "sproduct.html").

Whenever I select a product from the shop, the product details takes a place in the sproduct template, then, I press the "add-to-cart" button to add it to the shopping cart. Then, I get back to the shop to select another product.

The problems is:

When I press the "add-to-cart" button (representing a specific product at that moment), I lose the old saved data of the previously selected product in the dataset "cartData".

Here is my code for the HTML files and their Javascripts:

file: sproduct.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Blessed Sweets</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.4/css/all.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <script src="sproduct.js" async></script>
    </head>

        <!--################################# header & cover  ######################## -->

    <body>

        <section id="header">
            <a href="#"><img src="img/logo_lined0.png" class="logo" alt="" width="550" height="140" onclick="hrefFunctionHome()"></a>

            <div>
                <ul id="navbar">
                    <li><a herf="index.html" onclick="hrefFunctionHome()">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a class="active" herf="shop.html" onclick="hrefFunctionShop()">Shop</a></li>
                    <li><a herf="blog.html" onclick="hrefFunctionBlog()">Blog</a></li>
                    <li><a herf="about.html" onclick="hrefFunctionAbout()">About</a></li>
                    <li><a herf="contact.html" onclick="hrefFunctionContact()">Contact</a></li>
                    <li><a herf="cart.html" onclick="hrefFunctionCart()"><i class='fas fa-shopping-cart' style='font-size:30px;color:rgba(142, 19, 113, 0.878)'></i></a></li> 
            </div>
            
            <script>
                function hrefFunctionHome() {
                 window.location.href='index.html';
                 }
                function hrefFunctionShop(){
                    window.location.href='shop.html';
                    }
                    function hrefFunctionBlog() {
                        window.location.href='blog.html';
                        }
                        function hrefFunctionAbout() {
                            window.location.href='about.html';
                            }
                            function hrefFunctionContact() {
                                window.location.href='contact.html';
                                }
                                function hrefFunctionCart() {
                                    window.location.href='cart.html';
                                    }
             </script>
             <script>
                function hrefFunctionShop() {
                 window.location.href='shop.html';
                 }
             </script>
        </section>

        <section id="prodetails" class="section-p1"> 
            <div class="single-pro-img">
                <a class="single-pro-img-class"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="single-pro-details">
                <span class="prod-brand"></span>
                 <h5 class="prod-name"></h5>
                <div class="star">
                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                </div>
                <h5 class="prod-price"></h5>
                <select>
                    <option>SELECT TYPE OF NUTS (Stuffing and Decoration)</option>
                    <option>الكاوكاو</option>
                    <option>اللوز</option>
                    <option>الجوز</option>
                    <option>الفستق</option>ذ
                    <option>خليط من كل المكسرات</option>
                </select>
                <input type="number" value="1">
                <a class="add-cart-button"><button class="normal">Add To Cart</button></a> 
            </div>
        </section>


        <section id="newsletter" class="section-p1">
            <div class="newstext">
                <h4>Sign Up For News Letters</h4>
                <p>Get our updates for our latest products and offers</p>
            </div>
            <div class="form">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Your Email address">
                <button class="normal">Sign Up</button>
            </div>
        </section>

        <footer class="section-p1">
            <div class="col">
                <img class="logo" src="img/logo_lined0.png" alt="" width="250" height="70">
                <h4>CONTACT</h4>
                <p><strong>Address:</strong> 112, 112, El-Alia est, Biskra, Algeria</p>
                <p><strong>Phone:</strong> +213 556 10 66 16</p>
                <p><strong>Working Hours:</strong> 9:00  to  18:00 - Saturday To Thursday</p>
                <div class="follow">
                    <h4>FOLLOW US</h4>
                    <div class="icon">
                        <i class="fab fa-facebook-f" style='font-size:30px'></i>
                        <i class="fab fa-instagram" style='font-size:30px'></i>
                        <i class="fab fa-tiktok"style='font-size:30px'></i>                
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <h4>ABOUT</h4>
                <a href="#">About Us</a>
                <a href="#">Delivery Information</a>
                <a href="#">Privacy Policy</a>
                <a href="#">Terms and Conditions</a>
                <a href="#">Contact Us</a>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <h4>MY ACCOUNT</h4>
                <a href="#">Sign In</a>
                <a href="#">Help</a>
            </div>
            <div class="payment">
                <h4>PAYMENT METHOD</h4>
                <p>Secured Payment Getway With The Golden CARD</p>
                <img src="img/payment0.png" alt="" width="200" height="110">
                <span>البطاقة الذهبية</span>
            </div>

            <div class="copyright">
                <p>@ 2023, Blessed Sweets of Biskra</p>
            </div>
        </footer>

        <!-- <script>
            var MainImg = document.getElementById("MainImg");
            var smallimg = document.getElementsByClassName("small-img");

            smallimg[0]. onclick = function(){
                MainImg.src = smallimg[0].src;
            }
            smallimg[1]. onclick = function(){
                MainImg.src = smallimg[1].src;
            }
            smallimg[2]. onclick = function(){
                MainImg.src = smallimg[2].src;
            }

        </script> -->

        <script>


        </script>

    </body>

</html>
```

file: sproduct.js

```
if (document.readyState == 'loading') {
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', ready)
} else {
    ready()
}

function ready() {    // ############# ready to start ##################################

// ############# sproduct page and calculations ########################################

var addToCartButtons = document.getElementsByClassName('add-cart-button')
console.log(addToCartButtons)

    let sproductData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("sproductData"));
    console.log(sproductData)

    var sproductImgItems = document.getElementsByClassName("single-pro-img-class")[0]     // 1st Get the class where to add a line
    let sproducImgtHTML = `                
    <img src="${sproductData[3]}" width="100%" class="prod-img" id="MainImg" alt="">`   // 2nd write the line to be added including the vatiable
    sproductImgItems.innerHTML = sproducImgtHTML;   // 3rd Apply the line to the HTML code

    var sproductBrandItems = document.getElementsByClassName("prod-brand")[0]
    let sproductBrandHTML = `                
    Brand: ${sproductData[0]}`
    sproductBrandItems.innerHTML = sproductBrandHTML;

    var sproductNameItems = document.getElementsByClassName("prod-name")[0]     // 1st Get the class where to add a line
    let sproducNametHTML = `                
    Name: ${sproductData[1]}`   // 2nd write the line to be added including the vatiable
    sproductNameItems.innerHTML = sproducNametHTML;   // 3rd Apply the line to the HTML code

    var sproductPriceItems = document.getElementsByClassName("prod-price")[0]     // 1st Get the class where to add a line
    let sproducPricetHTML = `                
    Price: ${sproductData[2]}`   // 2nd write the line to be added including the vatiable
    sproductPriceItems.innerHTML = sproducPricetHTML;   // 3rd Apply the line to the HTML code

// ########## add to cart button ########################################################

    var addToCartButtons = document.getElementsByClassName('add-cart-button')
    console.log(addToCartButtons)
    const cartItem = [];
   
    var button = addToCartButtons[0]
    button.addEventListener('click', function (event){
        var button = event.target
        var shopItem = button.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement
        var title = shopItem.getElementsByClassName('prod-name')[0].innerText.replace('Name:','')
        var price = shopItem.getElementsByClassName('prod-price')[0].innerText.replace('Price:', '').replace('DZD', '')
        var imgSrc = shopItem.getElementsByClassName('prod-img')[0].src
        console.log(title, price, imgSrc)
        // return(title, price, imgSrc)
        const productItem = [title, price, imgSrc]
        cartItem.push(productItem);
    
        localStorage.setItem('cartData', JSON.stringify(cartItem));
        console.log(cartItem)

    });
}

// function addToCartClicked(event){
//     var button = event.target
//     var shopItem = button.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement
//     var title = shopItem.getElementsByClassName('prod-name')[0].innerText.replace('Name:','')
//     var price = shopItem.getElementsByClassName('prod-price')[0].innerText.replace('Price:', '').replace('DZD', '')
//     var imgSrc = shopItem.getElementsByClassName('prod-img')[0].src
//     console.log(title, price, imgSrc)
//     // return(title, price, imgSrc)
//     const productItem = [title, price, imgSrc]
//     cartItem.push(productItem);

//     // console.log(cartData)

//     localStorage.setItem('cartData', JSON.stringify(cartItem));
// }

    // const addButton = document.getElementById('add-to-cart');
    // const cartItems = [];
    
    // addButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
    //   // Get the product details
    //   const productName = prompt('Enter the product name:');
    //   const productPrice = prompt('Enter the product price:');
    
    //   // Add the product to the cart
    //   const product = { name: productName, price: productPrice };
    //   cartItems.push(product);
    
    //   // Save the cart to localStorage
    //   localStorage.setItem('cart', JSON.stringify(cartItems));
    // });

    // // Check if the cart data exists in localStorage
    // if (!localStorage.getItem('cartData')) {
    //     // If the cart data does not exist, initialize it as an empty array
    //     localStorage.setItem('cartData', JSON.stringify([]));
    //     const array1=[title, price, imgSrc]
    //     localStorage.setItem('cartData', JSON.stringify(cartData[0]));
    // }else{ 
    //     const array2=[title, price, imgSrc]
    //     localStorage.setItem('cartData', JSON.stringify(cartData[1]));
    // }
```

file: cart.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Blessed Sweets</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.4/css/all.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <script src="cart.js" async></script>

    </head>

        <!--################################# header & cover  ######################## -->


    <body>
        
        <section id="header">
            <a href="#"><img src="img/logo_lined0.png" class="logo" alt="" width="550" height="140" onclick="hrefFunctionHome()"></a>

            <div>
                <ul id="navbar">
                    <li><a herf="index.html" onclick="hrefFunctionHome()">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a herf="shop.html" onclick="hrefFunctionShop()">Shop</a></li>
                    <li><a herf="blog.html" onclick="hrefFunctionBlog()">Blog</a></li>
                    <li><a herf="about.html" onclick="hrefFunctionAbout()">About</a></li>
                    <li><a herf="contact.html" onclick="hrefFunctionContact()">Contact</a></li>
                    <li id="lag-bag"><a class="active" herf="cart.html" onclick="hrefFunctionCart()"><i class='fas fa-shopping-cart' style='font-size:30px;color:rgba(142, 19, 113, 0.878)'></i></a></li> 
            </div>
            
            <script>
                function hrefFunctionHome() {
                 window.location.href='index.html';
                 }
                function hrefFunctionShop(){
                    window.location.href='shop.html';
                    }
                    function hrefFunctionBlog() {
                        window.location.href='blog.html';
                        }
                        function hrefFunctionAbout() {
                            window.location.href='about.html';
                            }
                            function hrefFunctionContact() {
                                window.location.href='contact.html';
                                }
                                function hrefFunctionCart() {
                                    window.location.href='cart.html';
                                    }
             </script>
        </section>

        <section id="page-header" class="cart-header">
                <h2>#CheckTheBill</h2>
                <h3>!تحقق من فاتورتك</h3>
        </section>

        <section id="cart" class="section-p1">
            <table width="100%">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <td>REMOVE</td>    
                        <td>IMAGE</td>    
                        <td>PRODUCT</td>    
                        <td>PRICE</td>    
                        <td>QUANTITY</td>    
                        <td>SUBTOTAL</td>    
                    </tr>
                    <tbody class="cart-items">

                        
                    </tbody>
                </thead>
            </table>
        </section>

        <section id="cart-add" class="section-p1">
            <div id="coupon">
                <h3>Apply Coupon</h3>
                <div>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your coupon">
                    <button class="normal">Apply</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="subtotal">
                <h3>Cart Totals</h3>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Cart Subtotal</td>
                        <td class="cart-total-price"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Shipping</td>
                        <td>Free</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><strong>Total</strong></td>
                        <td class="cart-total-price"></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <button class="normal">Proceed to checkout</button>
            </div>
        </section>

        <!--################################# footer  ######################## -->
        <footer class="section-p1">
            <div class="col">
                <img class="logo" src="img/logo_lined0.png" alt="" width="250" height="70">
                <h4>CONTACT</h4>
                <p><strong>Address:</strong> 112, 112, El-Alia est, Biskra, Algeria</p>
                <p><strong>Phone:</strong> +213 556 10 66 16</p>
                <p><strong>Working Hours:</strong> 9:00  to  18:00 - Saturday To Thursday</p>
                <div class="follow">
                    <h4>FOLLOW US</h4>
                    <div class="icon">
                        <i class="fab fa-facebook-f" style='font-size:30px'></i>
                        <i class="fab fa-instagram" style='font-size:30px'></i>
                        <i class="fab fa-tiktok"style='font-size:30px'></i>                
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <h4>ABOUT</h4>
                <a href="#">About Us</a>
                <a href="#">Delivery Information</a>
                <a href="#">Privacy Policy</a>
                <a href="#">Terms and Conditions</a>
                <a href="#">Contact Us</a>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <h4>MY ACCOUNT</h4>
                <a href="#">Sign In</a>
                <a href="#">Help</a>
            </div>
            <div class="payment">
                <h4>PAYMENT METHOD</h4>
                <p>Secured Payment Getway With The Golden CARD</p>
                <img src="img/payment0.png" alt="" width="200" height="110">
                <span>البطاقة الذهبية</span>
            </div>

            <div class="copyright">
                <p>@ 2023, Blessed Sweets of Biskra</p>
            </div>
        </footer>

        <script>

                let cartData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cartData"));
                var cartItems = document.getElementsByClassName("cart-items")[0]

                for (var i = 0; i<cartData.length; i++) {
                    this["cartData"+i]=cartData[i]
                }

                    let cartHTML1 = `
                    <tr class="cart-row">
                        <td><a href="#" type="button" class="cart-remove-button"><i class="far fa-times-circle"></i></a></td>
                        <td><img src="${cartData0[2]}" alt=""></td>
                        <td>${cartData0[0]}</td>
                        <td class="cart-price">DZD ${cartData0[1]}</td>
                        <td><input class="cart-quantity-input" type="number" value="1"></td>
                        <td class="cart-sub-total">DZD ${cartData0[1]}</td>
                    </tr>`;
                    cartItems.innerHTML = cartHTML1;

                    let cartHTML2 = `
                    <tr class="cart-row">
                        <td><a href="#" type="button" class="cart-remove-button"><i class="far fa-times-circle"></i></a></td>
                        <td><img src="${cartData1[2]}" alt=""></td>
                        <td>${cartData1[0]}</td>
                        <td class="cart-price">DZD ${cartData1[1]}</td>
                        <td><input class="cart-quantity-input" type="number" value="1"></td>
                        <td class="cart-sub-total">DZD ${cartData1[1]}</td>
                    </tr>`;
                    cartItems.innerHTML = cartHTML1 + cartHTML2;

        </script>
          
    </body>

</html>
```

file: cart.js

```
if (document.readyState == 'loading') {
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', ready)
} else {
    ready()
}

function ready() {    // ############# ready to start ###############

// ############# cart page and calculations ###############


    var removeCartItemButtons= document.getElementsByClassName('cart-remove-button')
    console.log(removeCartItemButtons)
    for (var i = 0 ; i<removeCartItemButtons.length; i++) {
        var button = removeCartItemButtons[i]
        button.addEventListener('click', removeCartItem) 
    }

    var quantityInputs= document.getElementsByClassName('cart-quantity-input')
    for (var i = 0 ; i<quantityInputs.length; i++) {
        var input = quantityInputs[i]
        input.addEventListener('change', quantityChanged)

    }

    console.log(cartData)


    // // Check if the cart data exists in localStorage
    // if (!localStorage.getItem('cartData')) {
    // // If the cart data does not exist, initialize it as an empty array
    // localStorage.setItem('cartData', JSON.stringify([]));
    // }

    updateCartTotal()
    updateSubTotal()
}

function removeCartItem(event) {
    var buttonClicked = event.target
    buttonClicked.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.remove()
    updateCartTotal()
}

function quantityChanged(event){
    var input = event.target
    if (isNaN(input.value) || input.value <= 0) {
        input.value = 1
    }
    updateCartTotal()
    updateSubTotal()
}

function updateSubTotal() {
    var cartItemContainer = document.getElementsByClassName('cart-items')[0]
    var cartRows = cartItemContainer.getElementsByClassName('cart-row')
    for (var i = 0; i < cartRows.length; i++) {
        var cartRow = cartRows[i]
        var priceElement = cartRow.getElementsByClassName('cart-price')[0]
        var quantityElement = cartRow.getElementsByClassName('cart-quantity-input')[0]
        // console.log(quantityElement)
        var price = parseFloat(priceElement.innerText.replace('DZD', ''))
        console.log(price)

        var quantity = quantityElement.value
        subtotal = (price * quantity)
        console.log(subtotal)
        document.getElementsByClassName('cart-sub-total')[i].innerText = 'DZD ' + subtotal
    }
    // total = Math.round(total * 100) / 100
 
}

function updateCartTotal() {
    var cartItemContainer = document.getElementsByClassName('cart-items')[0]
    var cartRows = cartItemContainer.getElementsByClassName('cart-row')
    var total = 0
    for (var i = 0; i < cartRows.length; i++) {
        var cartRow = cartRows[i]
        var priceElement = cartRow.getElementsByClassName('cart-price')[0]
        var quantityElement = cartRow.getElementsByClassName('cart-quantity-input')[0]
        var price = parseFloat(priceElement.innerText.replace('DZD', ''))
        console.log(price)

        var quantity = quantityElement.value
        total = total + (price * quantity)
        console.log(total)
    }
    // total = Math.round(total * 100) / 100
    document.getElementsByClassName('cart-total-price')[0].innerText = 'DZD ' + total
    document.getElementsByClassName('cart-total-price')[1].innerText = 'DZD ' + total 
 
 
}

// for (var i = 0 ; i<removeCartItemButtons.length; i++) {
//     var button = removeCartItemButtons[i]
//     function removeCartRow() {
//     console.log('clicked')
//     var buttonClicked = event.target
//     buttonClicked.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.remove()
// }
// }
```

1. I expect saving and maintaining all the selected products after pressing the common "add-to-cart" button in the sproduct.html template. But it does achieve this.
2. I don't know how to creat a "for" loop that loops in the "cartData" and displays all the products in the cartData not only the first. I think this requires making the cartHTML variable in the "for" loop and I don't know how to achieve that.

How to solve the above two tasks?